# Switching 36 V DC motor with IRF3205 MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, switching

I'm attempting to switch a 36 V DC motor using an IRF3205 MOSFET, but I've now blown up two MOSFETs and I can't figure out why.

I've built the circuit as below, and it works correctly for about 30 seconds or so (the motor starts and stops as expected as the microswitch is closed and opened), but then the MOSFET is destroyed and the motor runs even without any gate input (i.e. with the switch open).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feWKYF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I'm reading the [data sheet for this MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRF3205-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355def244190a) correctly, it has a gate threshold voltage of 4 V and and a maximum gate-to-source voltage of 20 V. I have confirmed that the gate-to-source voltage from the LM317 is ~13 V, which if my understanding is correct, should mean the MOSFET is fully 'on' while being well below the maximum gate-source voltage. The 100K pull-down resistor from the gate to the source appears to correctly switch the MOSFET off when the switch is opened (prior to the MOSFET failing).

To be fair, I don't have the specs of the DC motor on hand, but running under zero load I absolutely expect that it is drawing nowhere near the 200 W maximum power of the MOSFET, which has a TO-220 heatsink installed and is barely warm to the touch.

What am I missing here? Additionally - happy for suggestions on a simpler circuit to achieve the same result :)

Comment: I'd be surprised if the LM317 timing was well defined. Guessing from the about 4 μs spikes in the transient plots, it might be fast enough. Turn-off may be a bit slow at 4.4 kΩ. I don't see a *de-bounce* for *microswitch*.

Comment: A voltage regulator as a gate driver is not a good plan--use a proper gate driver powered by your voltage regulator instead. I have no idea how the 317 will react to having its power cut, it may take much too long to turn off.

Comment: Where are the LM317 input and output capacitors?

Comment: (One thing I wouldn't know how to check would be an extremely high startup/stall current leading to very hot spots even where the case doesn't get "hot".)

Comment: @greybeard I was assuming the issue lie on the gate side of the MOSFET, but I think you could be onto the root cause of the issue there re: startup current. I just measured the motor running under no load, and while it sits at around 2 A, the MAX reading on my DMM shows a spike of ~8 A at startup. The IRF3205 data sheet states a maximum power dissipation of 200 W, but 8 A * 36 V = 288 W, so is it possible that the initial startup current is frying the MOSFET?

Comment: You can get a good guess on the current spike dividing supply voltage by the total resistance in "the motor circuit": voltage source (or buffer capacitor ESR), (semiconductor) switch, cabling, motor. Well, there are bound to be inductances, too.

Comment: Before I go frying more MOSFETs, if I were to run say 4 in parallel (linking the source, drain and separate 100 ohm gate resistor of each MOSFET to each other), is the current/power handling capability 4x?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, without decoupling capacitors at the input and output of the LM317 regulator, it's likely to behave very badly, and the output will ring or oscillate, exceeding your calculated output of 13V.

Even with appropriate capacitors, switching the input of a regulator in this manner is not a good way of obtaining a signal to operate the MOSFET's gate. These regulators are designed to be very low impedance voltage sources, which are good for providing high currents at a fixed potential, but your application here does not seem to require this. All you need, to operate the gate, is a potential that changes between 0V and some value somewhat under \$V_{GS(MAX)}\$, which can be obtained with a simple resistor divider:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fydU3B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With switch SW1 open, R2 holds gate potential at \$V_G = 0V\$, and the MOSFET is off. When the switch is closed R1 and R2 form a potential divider producing this potential at G:

$$V_G = 36V \times \frac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2} $$

Using the shown values for R1 and R2, this produces a gate potential of \$V_G=+13V\$ with SW1 closed, enough to turn on the MOSFET without exceeding its maximum \$V_{GS}\$.

Zener diode D2 is optional, the resistor divider is sufficient to ensure that  gate potential is capped at 13V. D2 provides another layer of security for the MOSFET, in case R2 somehow "disappears", causing gate potential to rise to the full +36V of the supply. D2 places two constraints on gate potential; it prevents \$V_G\$ from becoming more negative than -0.7V, or more positive than +15V.

This still may not be sufficient though. The gate driving circuitry here will switch the MOSFET on quite slowly, and for a brief time (especially when the motor starts from a complete stop), it may dissipate power beyond its safe operating area. You may need to drive the gate from a 0V/13V source of much lower impedance than R1 and R2,  to switch the MOSFET on and off more quickly. Consider using a proper gate driver IC.

In the meantime, you can make use of the LM317 in a slightly different way; instead of switching its input, switch the output, like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR5VzK.png)</sup>

I've included C1 and C2 to address their absence in your own design, and keep the LM317 from oscillating. It's output is a fixed 14V, and this low impedance source of 14V is applied or removed from the gate by SW1. In this way we avoid any overshoot, ringing or slow output slew that the regulator may exhibit when its *input* is switched on.

Since we now have a much lower impedance, and constant source of 14V (much better than R1 and R2 provided in the previous design), we are able to obtain much greater gate charging current (up to 1A or so), and R3 here can be very small, permitting the MOSFET to switch on much more rapidly.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the mosfet just as a slow switch on and off, as it will follow a user turning on and off, for this reason, you don't need a driver probably, as that will only speed up the turn on and off process.

You can just simplify the driving by using a voltage divider from your power supply. You can also add a zener to ensure the gate votlage is not beyond rating, something like:
[image]

About the device breaking, it would be interesting to know whether it is due thermal reasons or by switching. If you can leave it going and it just breaks by itselfs after X seconds then that's probably thermal breaking and you might need a larger mosfet or attaching a heatsink. If it is due to driving, you might be connecting the freewheeling diode backwards, your driving circuit might be messing with you (used my proposal instead).

Answer (score 0):

You have several possible problems, the LM317 is probably oscillating like crazy as there is no decoupling on it. This could cause heating in the MOSFET and LM317 as the oscilationing is generally not at full amplitude. The 100K pull down resistor is not needed as you have that on the regulator output. The pull down resistor when used should go on the driver side of the series resistor so you do not divide the gate drive voltage. If you have extra voltage as you do then it is no problem. Insufficient Gate voltage will cause the MOSFET to not be properly enhanced. I would like to see the gate resistor in the 100 Ohm range to give a fast turn on/off.

Comment: According to TI's datasheet, an output capacitor is optional with the LM317 `, but is not needed for stability` and would slow turn off, if not turn on to the same degree. An input capacitor is *recommended*, but there, it is assumed there *is* a filter/load capacitor.